# C++ vector of pointers to objects live

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I have a class which has a vector of pointers to objects of another class.

```
class Foo {
public:
Foo(vector<Member*> m);
Foo();
~Foo(void);

void addMember(Member* m);
vector<Member*> getMember(void);
private:
vector<Member*> m;
};
```

This is the cpp file

```
Foo::Foo( vector<Member*> m) {
this->m; 
}


void Foo::addMember(Member*m) {
this->m.push_back(m);
}

vector<Member*> Foo::getMember() {
return this->member;
}
```

When I try to add the objects :

```
foo[x].getMember().push_back(new Member);
```

I have an array of foo which I am passing to function where I am using the vector push_back. At the end of a function the Member obj destructor is called and when I try to reach the Member object I receive seg fault. What am I missing?

I fixed this using smart pointers as suggested. Thank you !

```
Member* m = new Member();
```

Comment: You're push_back-ing into a copy of the member variable because you return by value. This temporary copy gets destructed almost immediately. (P.S: all the this-> in your member functions are superfluous) (P.P.S: if your dtor does not explicitly delete all the objects in the vector youre leaking them) (P.P.P.S: I dont see why you new them in the first place)

Comment: why use a `std::vector<Member*>` when you could use a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Member> >`?

Comment: Fyi, `return this->member` -  there is no member variable `member` in any class declaration you've provided. Pretty sure you meant `m` (*please* use real code). And along that line, the vector returned from that `getMember()` function is a temporary; not a reference to the actual member variable (the vector). So you're pushing your `new Member` into what is about to become ether.

Comment: I changed it to :vector<Member*>& getMember(void); I no longer have errors. But how to prevent the destruction of Member object right after exiting the function ?

Comment: Please provide an MVCE that reproduces this issue. You are `new`ing a Member object, unless you explicitly delete it, it should not be destroyed.

Comment: @JasonPer When you add the `Member` object to the vector, presumably you want that vector to manage the lifetime of that object. So you should change your vector to hold unique_ptr's of the Member objects and it will be taken care of for you. Additionally you can add a `createMember` variadic template function which forwards its arguments to a call of `make_unique<Member>` for an efficient way to create new objects in the vector.

Comment: @Borgleader I've edited the post can you take a look at the bottom 
RyanP I will take a look at the smart pointers thank you